# Blazor server template throws exception on "Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area: }"

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I started to learn blazor with Linkedin and as I start a new blazor server project, based on VS22 (.net6), it throws me the following:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area:  }.
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DynamicPageEndpointMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

[image]

_Host.cshtml

```
@page "/"
@namespace FirstBlazorApp.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using FirstBlazorApp.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting(); 

app.MapBlazorHub();

app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Application .csproj code:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Does anyone face this issue?

Comment: Yes, I faced this exception in the past and solved the issue by fixing my code. The exception text was of no use at all. Please, provide a minimal, reproducible code snippet, including the _Host.cshtml file and the Program.cs file... as text, not as an image. Incidentally, where can one learn blazor with Linkedin ?

Comment: well, it's the template from vs so i didn't brought it here.

Comment: @ofergertz - you are right, this is standard template code. Does this really happen directly when you create a brand new project?  Or did you make some changes first? Try again, create a new project.

Comment: well yeah. it's happening while creating a blazor server app based on .net 6. while i'm trying to create blazor server app on .net 5 it's working fine.

Comment: I believe the issue resides in the  .csproj file. Could you please add the content of the file to your question.

Comment: edit the question with the app .csproj code

Answer (score 4):

This exception is shown even with brand new Blazor Server app template (target .NET6, .NET7 or .NET8) when using VS 2022 with enabled preview features. [image]
If I disable the preview features and restart the VS or if I use **VS 2022 Preview** this exception is not reproducible.
If you insist on using the preview, you can add this in your proj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseRazorSourceGenerator>false</UseRazorSourceGenerator>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Info:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36535

Comment: This answer solved the issue for me- I had not made any code changes to an app working just fine in .NET 6.0, but running it with the .NET 8.0 preview caused it to exhibit the error in OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2022 updates had solved the problem at my end.

Comment: Updated to which version? And how do you reached this? Please be more precisely